# mysql parse exception in simple case statement

Tags: mysql

I am honestly baffled why this simple case statement would throw a parse exception

```
case when (table.col1 = 'A' and table.col2 = 'X') then 
     coalesce(((col3 + col4)/(col5-col6))/floor(datediff(date('2022-11-11'), date('2022-08-27'))/7),0) 
     when (table.col1 = 'B' and table.col2 = 'X') then 
     coalesce((col3 + col4)/(col5-col6)),0) end as final
```

it works if I remove the second when statement

Comment: The brackets are not matched on the second coalesce.

Comment: *this simple case statement would throw a parse exception* Always provide complete error message text. And investigate it - server citates the part of the query, and it starts immediately from the char/letter where the problem is found.